# Why does my twitter-bootstrap navbar shrink on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

All,

When viewed **through a mobile device**, the navbar of my twitter-bootstrap page shrinks in height, and for the life of me, can't figure out why.

**Problem header:** 
http://openingofdetroit.org/

**Secondary site, no problem, pointing to same bootstrap files:** 
http://openingofdetroit.org/addyourvoice/

**Original template, no problem, pointing to original bootstrap files**
http://openingofdetroit.org/dev/jumbotron/

I've tried disabling as many CSS and JS files as I can think of, and haven't changed anything except a few widths in the original files, which by my troubleshooting above, isn't affecting the other two sites pointing to those CSS files.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the viewport meta tag on the home page.

Comment: Make sure to view through a mobile device